# tkinter context menu commands have no effect (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working in Python 3.5 and TKinteer.  Inside of a text widget, I have created a context menu that appears when the user right-clicks.  However, when I try and create the commands I want (cut, copy, paste), the commands seem to have no effect.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
class Application:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        root.title("Simple Text Editor")
        scrollBar = Scrollbar(root)
        self.textPad = Text(root, width=100, height=100, wrap='word',
                       yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set,
                       borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        scrollBar.config(command=self.textPad.yview)
        scrollBar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.textPad.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

class PopupMenu:
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        self.popup_menu = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
        self.popup_menu.add_command(label="Cut",
                                    command=lambda: app.textPad.event_generate('<Control-x>'))
        self.popup_menu.add_command(label="Copy",
                                    command=lambda: app.textPad.event_generate('<Control-c>'))
        self.popup_menu.add_command(label="Paste",
                                    command=lambda: app.textPad.event_generate('<Control-v>'))

        app.textPad.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)
        self.popup_menu.bind("<FocusOut>",self.popupFocusOut)

    def popup(self, event):
        self.popup_menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
        self.popup_menu.focus_set()

    def popupFocusOut(self, event=None):
        self.popup_menu.unpost()

root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
popupMenu = PopupMenu(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is that at the moment one of your popup commands is being invoked, the Text definitely doesn't have focus, and therefore won't receive your (simulated) keyboard events.  You could try explicitly focusing the Text before the `event_generate()`.

Comment: Are you running on OSX by any chance?

Comment: Bryan Oakley's answer works, but so does the suggestion from jasonharper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to generate `<Control-x>`, etc. Instead, generate the virtual events `<<Cut>>`, `<<Copy>>` and `<<Paste>>`.